# filter usage with a controller servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, model-view-controller, servlet-filters, servlet-3.0

For very simple MVC with JSP and servlet, what's the functionality of a filter?

There's a controller servlet in the example below, and then each JSP presents, I suppose, a different view.  The servlet interacts mostly with the model, a properties file with a list of users.  However, `login.jsp` will mutate the token, which is a session bean.

I realize that generally Spring, or facelets, or some other framework would come into play -- I'm just feeling my way.

It's a correct usage of filters for the servlet to use the filter?  I'm not sure how a filter would come into play here -- except that the "logic" of which JSP to dispatch to could maybe be extracted from the controller servlet and exist on its own in the filter...?

The JSP's wouldn't need access to the filter, since all dispatching is done through the servlet(?).

servlet:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.servlets;

import filter.PropertiesReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebServlet("/controller")
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Controller.class.getName());

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        log.info("controller processing request..");
        String jsp = dispatcherLogic(request.getSession());
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/" + jsp).forward(request, response);
    }

    private String dispatcherLogic(HttpSession session) {
        Properties properties = PropertiesReader.getProps();
        MyToken token = (MyToken) session.getAttribute("token");
        if (token != null) {
            token.setAuthenticated(properties.containsValue(token.getName()));
        } else {
            token = new MyToken();
        }
        log.info(token.toString());
        session.setAttribute("token", token);
        if (token.isAuthenticated()) {
            return "success.jsp";
        } else {
            if (token.isAttemptedLogin()) {
                return "fail.jsp";
            } else {
                return "login.jsp";
            }
        }
    }

    private String dispatcherLogic0(HttpSession session) {
        Map<String, String> p = PropertiesReader.getPropsAsMap();
        Enumeration<String> names = session.getAttributeNames();
        for (String s : Collections.list(names)) {
            log.info(s);
        }
        MyToken t = (MyToken) session.getAttribute("token");
        for (String s : p.keySet()) {
            //  t.getName() = p.containsValue(s);
        }
        return "hello.jsp";  //always to hello page for now
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "controller";
    }
}
```

filter:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.filter;

import filter.PropertiesReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

public class AuthenticateFilter implements Filter {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AuthenticateFilter.class.getName());
    private FilterConfig filterConfig = null;

    public AuthenticateFilter() {
    }

    private void doBeforeProcessing(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        log.info("do before processing..");
    }

    private void doAfterProcessing(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        log.info("do after processing");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        log.info("do filter");
    }

    public FilterConfig getFilterConfig() {
        return (this.filterConfig);
    }

    public void setFilterConfig(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    private void props() {
        log.info("properties file:");
        Properties properties = PropertiesReader.getProps();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
            String value = properties.getProperty(key);
            sb.append("\n" + key + " => " + value);
        }
        log.info(sb.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        log.info("init");

        this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
        if (filterConfig != null) {
            log.info("SessionCheckFilter:Initializing filter");
        } else {
            log.warning("null filterConfig");
        }

        props();

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (filterConfig == null) {
            return ("SessionCheckFilter()");
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("SessionCheckFilter(");
        sb.append(filterConfig);
        sb.append(")");
        return (sb.toString());
    }

    private void sendProcessingError(Throwable t, ServletResponse response) {
        log.info("send processing error");
        String stackTrace = getStackTrace(t);

        if (stackTrace != null && !stackTrace.equals("")) {
            try {
                response.setContentType("text/html");
                try (PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(response.getOutputStream()); PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(ps)) {
                    pw.print("<html>\n<head>\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n"); //NOI18N
                    pw.print("<h1>The resource did not process correctly</h1>\n<pre>\n");
                    pw.print(stackTrace);
                    pw.print("</pre></body>\n</html>"); //NOI18N
                }
                response.getOutputStream().close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        } else {
            try {
                try (PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(response.getOutputStream())) {
                    t.printStackTrace(ps);
                }
                response.getOutputStream().close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
    }

    public static String getStackTrace(Throwable t) {
        String stackTrace = null;
        try {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
            t.printStackTrace(pw);
            pw.close();
            sw.close();
            stackTrace = sw.getBuffer().toString();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        log.warning(stackTrace);
        return stackTrace;
    }

}
```

login token:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.servlets;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class MyToken {//should probably be immutable...

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyToken.class.getName());

    private String name = "nemo";
    private String role = "captain";
    private String password = "abc";
    private boolean authenticated = false;
    private boolean attemptedLogin = false;

    public MyToken() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean isAuthenticated() {
        return authenticated;
    }

    public void setAuthenticated(boolean authenticated) {
        this.authenticated = authenticated;
    }

    public boolean isAttemptedLogin() {
        return attemptedLogin;
    }

    public void setAttemptedLogin(boolean attemptedLogin) {
        this.attemptedLogin = attemptedLogin;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + authenticated + attemptedLogin;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A servlet does not interact with a filter. In fact, it does not even know if a filter was used (except through side effects). BTW your `AuthenticateFilter.doFilter` is bad. If you install such a filter in a web application, it will block everything since it never pass to the filterchain !

The logic of filters is as follow

```
servlet container prepares ServletRequest and ServletResponses objects and pass them to a *filter chain*
    first filter optional pre-processing pass down to next in chain
        second filter pre-processing
        ...
            Servlet processing
        ...
        second filter post-processing
    first filter optional post processing
servlet container pass (end of) data to client
```

The `doFilter` method is classicaly :

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    // optional pre-processing
    // optionaly return immediately to by-pass other filters and servlet processing
    chain.doFilter(request, response); // pass down to next filter or to servlet
                                       //  if last filter in chain
    // optional post-processing
}
```